# Reports templates not working on new install

Tags: wordpress, reports

I have installed version 4.7.13 in word press and am trying to get it working.  So far so good except for reports, when I try to use most of the reports I get an html page that I can't do anything with instead of the ones I see on the demo site
see pic.  Some look OK, like the activities detail but all the ones I want to use are messed up.  [image]

Comment: Oh yeah tried in opera, chrome, edge and exploder, no joy

Comment: any console errors ? You can get it by pressing F12 on the browser(Console Tab)

Comment: No, nothing when press F12